# Cannot Open Project the length of the project file exceeds the limit of 100 characters

Tags: android, file, import, character, project

I am using Android Studio 3.1 Preview and get an error when I attempt to import some projects:

Cannot Open Project 
The length of the project file exceeds the limit of 100 characters

This error occurs whether I am importing cloned projects from github or old projects I have saved with Eclipse. Is there a way to import these projects?

Answer (score 28):

In Android 3.1, if you are running up against the 100 character limit, instead of using Import project (File>New>Import Project), use File>Open, select your project, and then select the OK button.

I am not sure whether import offers some additional functionality beyond forcing you to rethink using long paths of > 100 characters.  For my purposes, using the File>Open method allows the selection of projects with long paths and preserves existing directory structures.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same problem with Android Studio 3.1 in **Linux**. After some tests I concluded that it considers the FULL path as the project length (from /home/ to Project root), which cant exceed 100 characters.

This warning message is also shown when you try to create a new project.

I didn't found where to customize it. So, as a workaround, check if you can reduce this full path length.

Best Regards

Comment: The problem is there are loads of projects on Github, even from a textbook I bought. Many projects I have tried to install give me the same error and I have had to manually copy source files and resources - ouch!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and solve this by limiting the character size. Try to limit your project name within 15 characters.

For example, if your project directory name like

> **some-name-of-the-project**

then you need to adjust the name within 15 characters

> **some-name-of-th**

I am looking for the setting to increase the length of the project name more than 15 characters.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows environment you could try to create a virtual driver as I'm doing. Use the [`subst`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST) command. For example I have the following giant path:

> C:\Users\MyUser\Source\Demos\Android\ud851-exercises\Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search\T02.05-Exercise-CreateAsyncTask

Using the command `subst E: "C:\Users\MyUser\Source\Demos\Android\ud851-exercises"` I can then import into Android Studio using the virtual path

> E:\Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search\T02.05-Exercise-CreateAsyncTask

It worked for me since I don't want to change anything in the repository's path.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone having this problem, it is simple. In my cases, the project folder is in a multiple stack folder. What I did is, I copy it and paste it directly in D folder.

```
D:/project-file.
```

Dont `D:/bla/bla-bla/project-file`

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if the number of characters in the full path(including the project root from /home or /Users) >= 100.

You can use this command to check: `pwd | wc -c`

Comment: This is probably one of the most stupid limitations I've ever seen

Answer (score 0):

Move your project folder for example into **C:** and rename the main folder to contains 1 char. It should looks like **C:a\android-project**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in android studio 3.1.3,when I change the project directory name to too short.Error clears.

For example, if your project directory name like

**Testingandroidsamplesomeprojectname**

Change to

**Testing**

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.3.2.
I have faced the same issue. Got following solution.
1.Best way to move your project from particular folder to another folder which contains the short path and then import from there. 
2.If you don't want to move your project then try to open it by File -> Open. After that it may not build properly. Then just do File -> Re-Import Gradle Project. It will solve your problem.